# Laravel : Search Query Within Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

When I am adding a new post in my app there is a `7 tables` to affect when I add single post. To fetch all posts with all post data  my simple query look like:

```
$userPost   = Post::with(['product','postattribute.attribute.category','user.userDetails'])
                        ->offset($offset)
                        ->limit($limit)
                        ->whereStatus("Active")
                        ->whereIn('product_id', $userApprovalProductIDs)
                        ->orderBy('id','desc')
                        ->get();
```

So it is retrun all data which I want. Now I want to implement search query within all tables, currently I am able to search only `posts` table.

If I am doing search on `category` table with `categoryTitle` I am trying to code like

```
where('category.title','=', $serachTitle)
```

But it is not working in my case.

`POST` model relationship :

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}

public function postattribute() {
    return $this->hasMany(PostAttribute::class);
}
```

`POSTATTRIBUTES` model relationship :

```
  public function post() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

 public function attribute() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class);
}
```

`ATTRIBUTES` model relationship :

```
   public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

 public function attributes() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class);
}
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Can you include your model definitions ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid ok wait ,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply filter on your nested relations you could use `whereHas`

```
$userPost   = Post::with(['product','postattribute.attribute.category','user.userDetails'])
    ->offset($offset)
    ->limit($limit)
    ->whereStatus("Active")
    ->whereIn('product_id', $userApprovalProductIDs)
    ->whereHas('postattribute.attribute.category', function ($query) use($serachTitle) {
        $query->where('title', '=', $searchTitle);
    })
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->get();
```

[Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

From comments what i understood is you want to know how to search within each relation for a post , I already added an example to search with category title

```
->whereHas('postattribute.attribute', function ($query) use($var) {
    $query->where('some_field_of_attribute_table', '=', $var);
})

->whereHas('postattribute', function ($query) use($var) {
    $query->where('some_field_of_postattribute_table', '=', $var);
})
```

Comment: what should i do if `postattribute.attribute.category` all tables have a same field for `title`? how can i validate for particular table @MKhalidJunaid

Comment: *all tables have a same field for title* I didn't get this can explain it more or would be better if you could update your question

Comment: this 3 tables `postattribute.attribute.category` all have one Same field which is  `post_id`. If i want to seach within `postattribute` table with `post_id` how can i differ from `attribute.category` table.

Comment: @Javed I have updated my answer let me know if it clears out your issue